# ERROR No package identifier when getting value for resource number

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Both activities are in the same package

Second activity uses second layout file

```
setContentView(R.layout.main2);
```

Errors on this line in the Second_Activity.

```
EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText03);
```

Here is the layout file for the Second_Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Answer Is : " >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Calling an intent" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the errors in the LogCat window

```
08-01 19:32:20.340: WARN/ResourceType(8875): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000005
08-01 19:32:20.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8875): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
```

mail.xml

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="First Number : ">
</TextView>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
```

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Second Number: ">
</TextView>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditText02" 
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
```

secondscreen.xml

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView03" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Answer Is : ">
</TextView>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/main2EditText01" 
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
```

manifest xml file

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo"/>
```

Comment: There's something syntactically wrong with your XML files that's stopping your ids in R from being generated. Could you post the rest of your XMLs? Maybe you're missing a close tag or something.

Comment: new here not sure how to put the xml files in as a reply

Comment: Oh; pasting it in your question is fine. :)

Comment: Hmm.. I can't see anything wrong with what you posted; Did you put your views in a layout (is the layout xml correct?)?

Comment: I changed it from an EditText to a TextFiled  and it worked just fine.  Odd

Comment: typo on my part in the xml file  did not see the red x in the circle  yes I am human... this and many other things prove it

Answer (score 111):

I got this same error message when I tried to use TextView.setText passing a char instead of a String.    This makes sense since the char would be promoted to an int which meant that I was really calling the

```
TextView.setText( int resId );
```

And since there wasn't a resource with that value, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to send an Integer with setText(). Using  Integer.toString did the trick for me.

Comment: This is the actual reason for this question. I didn't scroll down and tried to with accepted answer. But I figured it finally and came here to put it as an answer. But @John already have put that :) I used TextView.setText(String.valueOf(myIntValue));

Comment: had exact same issue

Answer (score 42):

face with the same error

finally i found its not a error due to your xml layout

somewhere in your code set `TextView.setText(int)`

try `TextView.setText( Integer.toString(int));`

Comment: I was fighting this for a good hour, turns out I was doing everything fine except passing a String to setText(), thanks!

Answer (score 9):

When you pass an integer to the `TextView.setText()` to be displayed android assumes it is a resource id and that's why you are getting `Resource$NotFoundException`. Try converting the int to String before passing it to `TextView.setText()`: `TextView.setText(String.valueOf(i))`.

Answer (score 7):

Just for the protocol, You could also use:

`TextView.setText("" + intVar)` instead of `TextView.setText(intVar)`

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error while trying to print integer value : TextView.setText(int value).
I resolved this error by converting the integer value to string and the i used
TextView.setText(converted string value)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem before I come to this post.
For me, it was like this: `view_element.setText( an_int_value)`.
After casting `view_element.setText(String.valueOf(an_int_value));`, everything is okay.

Answer (score 4):

From [Android TextView Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView):

> - `setText(int resid)` Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.

Answer (score 3):

It is due to typecast error.
You have to try this-
TextView.setText(Integer.toString(variable_name));

Here toString is used to convert integer to string for showing text.

Comment: it does not answer the question at all... the problem here is obviously about id not being generated properly

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to go in the XML file for the button. There I noticed a hard coded string value. I had to remove that, and also I had to use `Textview.setText("" + intVar);`

Answer (score 0):

I was using Picasso library to load image from the network. The urls are in a ArrayList I wasn't using arraylist.get() to get the position of the url in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem, when i was trying to integrate SocialAuth libray with my Android application with Android Studio. What was my problem was, some of my resources like facebook icon, were in the **mipamp** folder. I moved it to **drawables** folder and the issue got fixed.