# Android TableLayout - No package identifier Issue

Tags: android

i've a problem with my app.

I have a website where I have a ranking table.
I want get from this table all usernames, points and bonuses.

I use a Asynctask for send a HttpRequest through Jsoup to my website.

After i parse my html String, i save in 3 arrays all usernames, points and bonuses.

Ok, now i want to create a dynamic table and i use TableLayout in my main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</TableLayout>
```

This is the application code:

```
package it.android.mypackage;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    TableLayout chartTable;
    String[] users;
    String[] points;
    String[] bonuses;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chartTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

        String pathURL = "http://mywebsite.com/chart.aspx";

        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(pathURL);

    }

    class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            String url = urls[0];
            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            response = doc.toString();
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Document doc = null;

            doc = Jsoup.parse(result);

            Elements listUsers = doc
                    .select("tr[style=border-bottom: 2px solid black;] td:eq(2)");
            Elements listPoints = doc
                    .select("tr[style=border-bottom: 2px solid black;] td:eq(3)");
            Elements listBonuses = doc
                    .select("tr[style=border-bottom: 2px solid black;] td:eq(4)");


                users = (listUsers.text()).split(" ");
                points = (listPoints.text()).split(" ");
                bonuses = (listBonuses.text()).split(" ");

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView positiontv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                positiontv.setText(i+1);
                positiontv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView usernametv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                usernametv.setText(users[i]);
                usernametv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                TextView pointstv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                pointstv.setText(points[i]);
                pointstv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                TextView bonusestv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                bonusestv.setText(bonuses[i]);
                bonusestv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tr.addView(positiontv);
                tr.addView(usernametv);
                tr.addView(pointstv);
                tr.addView(bonusestv);

                chartTable.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When i debug my app i've an Exception and in the LogCat i can see:

```
09-06 14:58:21.230: W/ResourceType(29801): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
```

I have this error on

```
positiontv.setText(i+1);
```

and on three other TextView in setText() method.

```
usernametv.setText(users[i]);
pointstv.setText(points[i]);
bonusestv.setText(bonuses[i]);
```

I don't understand where is the problem.

Some one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3399774/741249?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by replacing:

```
positiontv.setText("" + i+1);
usernametv.setText("" + users[i]);
pointstv.setText("" + points[i]);
bonusestv.setText("" + bonuses[i]);
```

:)