# No package identifier when getting value for resource number

Tags: android

I have read question with similar titles already.
[image]

Like you can see there is not much info.

I have checked in the R file there is no 0x00000021c resource.

This happens when I press a button and I am creating a new Intent and I want to load a new Activity to the screen. It is like a "Next screen" button...

The new **activity is big**, and right now I am splitting the dynamic and the static parts: a lot of xml-s, and not a simple one with 1-2 view. Around total 100 view?

As I saw the other questions and answers I think I have somewhere a .setText("Some invalid stuff here")

**Any idea how to find that line, except with debugger step by step over thousand of lines?**

Comment: not a real solution, but may be helpful: Log any Method call with the Method name to LogCat. The last method which is triggered must be the cause of your problem. Debug only that method.

Comment: plz post Button onclick code with question

Comment: I told it is thousands of line happening on the onClick()

Comment: @matheszabi : ok then in onclick of Button probably  u are passing Integer in `TextView.setText(...)` plz check it

Comment: Can you try regenerating your R file? This can usually be done by running an `ant clean` or just deleting the bin and gen folders in your project.

Comment: @hwrdprkns ofc that I did before I post here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR No package identifier when getting value for resource number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399774/error-no-package-identifier-when-getting-value-for-resource-number)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please check also the button setting values, and do a `setText(""+intValue)` instead of `setText(intValue)`

Comment: Or use setText(Integer.toString(...)) , which is better.