# Unable to get value from Java HashMap by using Key

Tags: java, android, exception, hashmap

This is my HashMap object:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> kart = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String pIndex="Any Index Value";
int value=anyIntegerValue;
```

Code to update kart:

```
Globals.kart.put(pIndex, value);
```

Code to check index and get value:

```
String inKart = "Product is not in Kart";
if(Globals.kart.containsKey(pIndex)){
    int count = Globals.kart.get(pIndex);
    inKart = "Product is in Kart " + count;
}
System.out.print(inKart);
```

It is successfully checking the key, but when it tries to get value from kart on the basis of key, it throws an exception, **String reource ID #0x1**.

```
No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

All examples showing that I can get the value by using String key, but it's not working for me. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I have edited some typing mistakes and re-written some variable names to what I have written in original code.

Please not that if I am checking the key using **containsKey(pIndex)**, it is not giving any error. Exception occurs only in the line**kart.get(pIndex)**.

Some comments are mentioning that the error has nothing to do with HashMap. If this is the case then please explain why this code is throwing the exception only that particular line in Android.

Comment: Is `kart` supposed to be the same as `Globals.kart` ?

Comment: Where is your method call for the resources?

Comment: The exception doesn't related to HashMap and code snippet in the question.

Comment: Given error is not related to maps at all

Comment: Yes kart and Globals.kart is same. I have edited some typing mistakes in question. Please read it again

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja can you please explain what is the cause of the eroor?

Comment: @Andremoniy can you please provide a solution?

Comment: here is a stackoverflow question about that specific error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399774/error-no-package-identifier-when-getting-value-for-resource-number

Comment: @ArmandoSM, you made my day. Problem solver. It was a kinder garden mistake. Integer values was fabricated as char not as string. Just do explicit string typecast. Thanks sir. To bad I can't accept your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashMap is returning an integer value and was fabricated either as integer or char in TextView. So I typecast it explicitly with String and all is well.

Thanks again.

Ram Ram